# Mono for Android LocationManager exception Closing Channel

Tags: android, mono, gps

I am debugging an app that is failing with GPS problems.

I have tried the standard GetLocation sample, and I receive the same error.

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Recipes/OS%2F%2FDevice_Resources/GPS/Get_Current_Device_Location

The application shuts down, and the application output window shows the following:

Using gps.
Listening for location updates using gps.
channel '40745d58 GetLocation.GetLocation/com.xamarin.recipes.getlocation.Activity1 (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

I am testing this in an emulator. I have allowed all the location permissions in the manifest,  FINE,  COARSE and MOCK.

I set a mock location in the emulator with geo fix via telnet,  but the app just dies after a few seconds.

The emulator then hangs showing the "ANDROID" screen, and I need to close and re-open it to get it to respond again.

The emulator has GPS hardware selected, and is running Android 2.3

Any ideas ?

Comment: I am having the same exact issue....GPS never updates, no errors thrown, and the emulator dies.  Using MonoForAndroid_API_10